# Stiefel-Whitney class of complex projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $T\mathbb{C}P^m$ be the tangent bundle of complex projective space. What is the total Stiefel-Whitney class $w(T\mathbb{C}P^m)$?

Let $a_m$ be the maximal integer such that the $a_m$-th dual Stiefel-Whitney class $\bar w_{a_m}(T\mathbb{C}P^m)$  is nonzero ($\bar w=1/w$, $\bar w_j$ is the degree-$j$-component of $\bar w$). Can we write $a_m$ in terms of $m$?

I do not know how to solve. I even do not know how to solve the case $m=2$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^m; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{m+1})$ where $\deg \alpha = 2$, and

$$w(T\mathbb{CP}^m) = (1 + \alpha)^{m+1} = 1 + \binom{m+1}{1}\alpha + \binom{m+1}{2}\alpha^2 + \dots + \binom{m+1}{m}\alpha^m.$$

where the coefficients are taken modulo $2$.

In a (truncated) polynomial ring, $(1 - \beta)^{-1} = 1 + \beta + \beta^2 + \dots$ Setting $\beta = 1 - w(T\mathbb{CP}^m)$, this gives a formula for $\overline{w}(T\mathbb{CP}^m)$ from which we can read off $a_m$.

For example, $w(T\mathbb{CP}^4) = 1 + \binom{5}{1}\alpha + \binom{5}{2}\alpha^2 + \binom{5}{3}\alpha^3 + \binom{5}{4}\alpha^4 = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^4$, so

$$\overline{w}(T\mathbb{CP}^4) = 1 + (\alpha + \alpha^4) + (\alpha + \alpha^4)^2 + (\alpha  + \alpha^4)^3 + (\alpha + \alpha^4)^4 = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3$$

and hence $a_4 = 6$.

Here are the first few values of $a_m$.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
m & w(T\mathbb{CP}^m) & \overline{w}(T\mathbb{CP}^m) & a_m\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 & 1 + \alpha & 2\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
4 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^4 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 & 6\\
5 & 1 + \alpha^2 + \alpha^4 & 1 + \alpha^2 & 4\\
6 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 + \alpha^5 + \alpha^6 & 1 + \alpha & 2\\
7 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
8 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^8 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 + \alpha^5 + \alpha^6 + \alpha^7 & 14\\
9 & 1 + \alpha^2 + \alpha^8 & 1 + \alpha^2 + \alpha^4 + \alpha^6 & 12\\
10 & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 = \alpha^8 + \alpha^9 + \alpha^{10} & 1 + \alpha + \alpha^4 + \alpha^5 & 10
\end{array}

It appears as if $a_m = 2s_m$ where $s_m$ is the $m^{\text{th}}$ term of [$A035327$](https://oeis.org/A035327) on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. That is, $s_m$ is the value obtained by writing $m$ in binary, interchanging zeroes and ones, and then reverting back to decimal. For example, $m = 4 = 100_2$ and $011_2 = 3$ so $s_4 = 3$ and $a_4 = 6$.

To see why this is the case, write $m = 2^{i_1} + \dots + 2^{i_k}$ with $0 \leq i _1 < \dots < i_k = \lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor$, then $s_m = 2^{j_1} + \dots + 2^{j_l}$ where $\{j_1, \dots, j_l\} = \{0, \dots, \lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor\}\setminus\{i_1, \dots, i_k\}$. Then $m + s_m = 2^0 + 2^1 + \dots + 2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor - 1} + 2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor} = 2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor + 1} - 1$ so

$$(1 + \alpha)^{m+1}(1+\alpha)^{s_m} = (1 + \alpha)^{m + 1 + s_m} = (1 + \alpha)^{2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor + 1}} = 1 + \alpha^{2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor + 1}} = 1$$

as $2^{\lfloor\log_2(m)\rfloor + 1} \geq m + 1$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\overline{w}(T\mathbb{CP}^m) &= (1 + \alpha)^{s_m}\\ 
&= (1 + \alpha)^{2^{j_1} + \dots + 2^{j_k}}\\ 
&= (1 + \alpha)^{2^{j_1}}\dots(1 + \alpha)^{2^{j_k}}\\ 
&= \left(1 + \alpha^{2^{j_1}}\right)\dots\left(1 + \alpha^{2^{j_k}}\right)\\ 
&= 1 + \dots + \alpha^{2^{j_1}+\dots + 2^{j_k}}\\
&= 1 + \dots + \alpha^{s_m}.
\end{align*}

Note that $s_m < m$, so $\alpha^{s_m} \neq 0$ and hence $a_m = 2s_m$.

Comment: Dear Michael, how is $(ℂℙ^2)=1++^2$ with an odd $$ consistent with the other answer by Georges Elencwajg saying that $_{2+1}(_ℝ)=0$  for the odd Stiefel-Whitney classes of underlying real vector bundle is zero?

Comment: If I read your data $w(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2$ with $\deg =2$, then $w_2(T\mathbb{CP}^2)=w_4(T\mathbb{CP}^2)=1 \mod 2$? Also that the $\mathbb{CP}^2$ orientable so the 1st class $w_1(T\mathbb{CP}^2)=0 \mod 2$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $w_2(T\mathbb{CP}^2)$ is $1 \bmod 2$ as $w_2(T\mathbb{CP}^2) \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2; \mathbb{Z})$ not in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the two groups are isomorphic, but not equal). One way to view the expression $w(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2$ is that $w_1(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = w_3(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = 0$, while $w_2(T\mathbb{CP}^2)$ and $w_4(T\mathbb{CP}^2)$ are non-zero.

Answer (score 7):

A  topological complex  vector bundle $E$ on a manifold $M$  has Chern classes $c_i(E)\in H^{2i}(M;\mathbb Z)$ and its underlying  real vector bundle $E_\mathbb R$ has Stiefel-Whitney classes $w_j(E_\mathbb R)\in H^{j}(M;\mathbb Z/2)$.
The relation betwen both could not be more idyllic:

$\bullet $ The odd Stiefel-Whitney classes of $E_\mathbb R$ vanish: $w_{2j+1}(E_\mathbb R)=0$.
$\bullet \bullet$ The canonical map  $H^{2i}(M;\mathbb Z)\to H^{2i}(M;\mathbb Z/2)$ sends $c_i(E)$ to $w_{2i}(E_\mathbb R)$.

In the case of $E=T_{\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)}$ we have $c_i(T_{\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)})=\binom{n+1}{i}\in  H^{2i}(P^n(\mathbb C);\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ and $c_i(T_{\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)})=0$ for  $i\gt n$.
Thus reducing mod. $2$ we get $w_{2i}((T_{\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)})_\mathbb R)=\binom{n+1}{i} \operatorname{mod. 2}\in  H^{2i}(P^n(\mathbb C);\mathbb Z/2)=\mathbb Z/2$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ and all the other Stiefel-Whitney classes of $(T_{\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)})_\mathbb R$ are zero.

**Bibliography**
[Milnor-Stasheff](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Characteristic_Classes.html?id=5zQ9AFk1i4EC&redir_esc=y),  Theorem 14.10 page 169 and Problem 14-B page 171.

Comment: In your formula, do you really suggest that $w_0(\mathbb{CP}^1)=1$,  $w_2(\mathbb{CP}^1)=0$, $w_4(\mathbb{CP}^1)=1$?  and others $w_j(\mathbb{CP}^1)=0$ ?

Comment: Similarly, in your formula, do you really suggest that $w_0(\mathbb{CP}^2)=1$,  $w_2(\mathbb{CP}^2)=1$, $w_4(\mathbb{CP}^2)=1$, $w_6(\mathbb{CP}^2)=1$?  and others $w_j(\mathbb{CP}^2)=0$ ?

Comment: @annie: it does not make sense to write things like $w_4(\mathbb  {CP}^1)=1$ and any reasonable interpretation of that equality is false, so that I certainly  did not "suggest it" I have written very precise results about characteristic classes of **vector bundles** on complex manifolds and if you do not believe them tell me what you think is wrong. But use my notations and do not replace them by  your ambiguous  ones.

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, how is Michael Albanese answer that $(ℂℙ^2)=1++^2$ with an odd $$ consistent with the your answer saying that $_{2+1}(_ℝ)=0$  for the odd Stiefel-Whitney classes of underlying real vector bundle is zero?

Comment: Sorry perhaps $\deg =2$.

Comment: @annie marie coeur:  Yes, $\deg \alpha=2$.